# Is it possible to have a Button(action: -) in a List/ForEach view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to add a `Button(action: -` view to a List view with a `ForEach` in it which has a `NavigationLink` in it. So a user can look at a detail screen of list which has a `Button(action: -` however if they if user does not need to see details they can select using `Button` in list.

```
List {
  ForEach(DATA, id: \.self { data in
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(data: data)) {
      HStack {
        Text(data.name)
        Button(action: {
           // add to an array
        }) {
             Text(data.price)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when i click on the button always take to DetailView

Not sure if it possible. Any advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
List {
  ForEach(DATA, id: \.self { data in
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(data: data)) {
      HStack {
        Text(data.name)
        Button(action: {
           // add to an array
        }) {
             Text(data.price) // some padding might be useful
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue) // << can be any 
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())    // << here !!
      }
    }
  }
}
```